# CASE AND WHEN SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have transactional data of customers' purchase. I tried to select customer_id from the last 1 month and calculate recency as the average day customers come to purchase (AVG(gap))

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    (
        CASE WHEN day::DATE<= '2015-05-01'::DATE AND day::DATE > '2015-05-01'::DATE - INTERVAL '1 month' 
            THEN
            (
                SELECT
                    AVG(gap)
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        customer_id,
                        ( day- LAG(day) OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY day ) ) AS gap
                    FROM
                        baskets
                    JOIN
                        basket_lines
                    USING
                        ( basket_id )
                    GROUP BY 1
                ) a
            ) b
            ELSE 0
        ) AS A
FROM
    baskets
JOIN
    basket_lines
USING
    (basket_id)
GROUP BY
    1;
```

However, I have an error like `

```
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "b"
 LINE 45:    GROUP BY 1)a)b ELSE 0) AS A
                          ^
```

Does it mean I can not use subquery after `THEN` statement?

Comment: Your `CASE WHEN` statement needs an `END` to terminate it after the `ELSE`. Note that using subqueries inside `SELECT` is generally bad practice. I also recommend always specifying aliases with `AS` to avoid cryptic syntactic soup like `BY 1) a) ELSE 0 END) AS A`.

Comment: Please post your table definitions and some sample data.

Comment: It seems strange that your subquery is not related to your main query. Then in the innermost query you group by `customer_id`, but still try to access the `day` column. Either there is just one record per `customer_id`, then you don't need to group by it, or it is not, then you'd need an aggregate function on `day` to tell the DBMS which day of the customer's days you are referring to.

Comment: Which table does `customer_id` reside in? Which table does `day` reside in?

Comment: Your query is way too complicated.  Ask *another* question.  Provide sample data, desired result, and a better explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery in the `THEN` clause does not take an alias.  Also, you must end your `CASE` expression with `END`:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    (CASE WHEN day::DATE<= '2015-05-01'::DATE AND
               day::DATE > '2015-05-01'::DATE - INTERVAL '1 month' 
          THEN
          (SELECT AVG(gap) FROM (
               SELECT customer_id,
                   (day- LAG(day) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY day)) as gap
               FROM baskets
               JOIN basket_lines
               USING (basket_id)
               GROUP BY 1) a) ELSE 0 END) AS A
FROM baskets
JOIN basket_lines
USING (basket_id)
GROUP BY 1;
```

But you have a correlated subquery in your select statement.  This is probably not optimal, and we can likely rewrite your query using a join.

I propose the following refactor:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        (day- LAG(day) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY day)) as gap
    FROM baskets
    INNER JOIN basket_lines
    USING (basket_id)
    WHERE day::DATE<= '2015-05-01'::DATE AND
          day::DATE > '2015-05-01'::DATE - INTERVAL '1 month' 
)

SELECT
    customer_id,
    AVG(gap) AS cust_avg
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    customer_id;
```

Comment: Homesand's  subquery doesn't seem to be correlated at all, but this is likely to be a mistake :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes...I also saw this.  I suggested a refactor which might be an improvement.